# Swift : stacking text vertically in horizontal line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text

Is there a way in Swift to have casually vertical stacked text inline ?
I'm outputting chord names for instance in a part of my app, and I'd like to have some parts stacked vertically in braces such as in this example :

[image: chord]

(here there's only 2 elements stacked but it could go up to 6 elements in a 2 times 3 vertical ones fashion)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a vertical StackView (for the *♭5* and the *add 13*) within a horizontal StackView and just change the height of the texts accordingly.

[image: Just like that.]

Comment: will try that !